# C++ class templates with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, class, pointers, templates

I am just learning how to use templates in c++, and I am struggling a bit. I have an example below, with comments at the points where I'm getting hung up.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int arrayOneSize, int arrayTwoSize>
class myClass{
  public:
    myClass(){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOneSize; i++){
        arrayOne[i] = i;
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < arrayTwoSize; i++){
        arrayTwo[i] = i;
      } 
    }
    
    int arrayOne[arrayOneSize];
    int arrayTwo[arrayTwoSize];
    
    void printArrayElements(){
      for(int i = 0; i < arrayOneSize; i++){
        cout << arrayOne[i] << '\n';
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < arrayTwoSize; i++){
        cout << arrayTwo[i] << '\n';
      }
    }
    void someOtherFunction();
};

// can't figure out how to define constructors or functions outside of class
void myClass::someOtherFunction(){

}

template <int numInstances>
class myClassContainer{
  public:
    myClassContainer(){
        for(int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++){
            myClassInstances[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    
    // this doesn't work
    template<int, int> myClass<int, int> *myClassInstances[numInstances];
    
    // also doesn't work
    void addClassInstance(myClass *instance){
        for(int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++){
            if(myClassInstances[i] == NULL){
                myClassInstances[i] = instance; 
            }
        }
    }
    
    void printAll(){
      for(int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++){
        myClassInstances[i]->printArrayElements();
      }
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    myClass<5,6> myClass1;
    myClass<1,4> myClass2;
    myClassContainer<2> container;
    container.addClassInstance(&myClass1);
    container.addClassInstance(&myClass2);
    container.printArrayElements();

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to pass pointers to myClass instances into myClassContainer, but I can't figure out the template syntax. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: `template<int arrayOneSize, int arrayTwoSize>
void myClass<arrayOneSize,arrayTwoSize>::someOtherFunction(){
    cout << arrayOneSize << " " << arrayTwoSize << '\n';
}`  https://onlinegdb.com/7bdzABlB8

Comment: @JerryJeremiah If you need the `template` stuff, you'll also need it to be `inline` since it'll be in the header but not actually inside the body of the class definition.

Comment: @NathanPierson All template definitions are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: @Bapstack `myClass<5,6>` and `myClass<1,4>` are different types. You can't store them in the same array unless you do some type-erasure tricks (but you would probably need to restore the type eventually, which gets more and more difficult).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Oops, well, I've learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link handy explicitly stating that? It doesn't appear to be stated in [cppreference's page on member templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template), [class templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template), or [the inline specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). I'm sure it's somewhere I'm not thinking to look though.

Comment: If your class template should provide a common interface, the right thing to do is have it inherit from an abstract base class and leverage polymorphism.  Then you can store instances of that in a single container (with a pointer/smart pointer) and/or pass the interface to a function as pointer or reference type.

Comment: @NathanPierson Okay, I'm not sure if "implicitly `inline`" is the correct phrase, but the effect is the same - template function definition in mutliple translation units won't violate One Definition Rule (as long as each definition is exactly the same): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I will implement the changes today. The one thing I'm still not sure how to work around is my class container with different myClass types. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to clump all of the instances of myClass together for easy iterating, even if the template arguments are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can't figure out how to define constructors or functions outside of class
>
> `void myClass::someOtherFunction(){}`

The problem here is that there is no class called `myClass`. Instead, there are only classes called `myClass<someNumber, anotherNumber>`. So, in order to define `someOtherFunction`, it must be written something like:

```cpp
void myClass<someNumber, anotherNumber>::someOtherFunction() { ... }
```

However, neither `someNumber` nor `anotherNumber` are a concrete number,  so you need to make them template parameters:

```cpp
template<int someNumber, int anotherNumber>
void myClass<someNumber, anotherNumber>::someOtherFunction() { ... }
```

Also note, it's more common and convenient to use the same template names as the ones used in the class declaration, so your definition would be:

```cpp
template<int arrayOneSize, int arrayTwoSize>
void myClass<arrayOneSize, arrayTwoSize>::someOtherFunction() { ... }
```

---

> this doesn't work
> `template<int, int> myClass<int, int> *myClassInstances[numInstances];`

The problem here is that the types of all class member must be known at the time the class was defined. So you can not have a member with a template class that cannot deduce its type at the time the outer class is defined. So you need to either:

1. Assign both template parameters with some concrete value:

```cpp
template <int numInstances>
class myClassContainer{
    myClass<2, 3> *myClassInstances[numInstances];
};
```

2. You can use the template parameter of `myClassContainer` to calculate a value:

```cpp
myClass<numInstances, numInstances * 2> *myClassInstances[numInstances];
```

3. Or you can make both of them template parameter, and add them to the class template parameters:

```cpp
template <int numInstances, int A, int B>
class myClassContainer{
    myClass<A, B> *myClassInstances[numInstances];
};
```

4. Of course you can do any mixture of them

Do note that whichever approach you decided on, you cannot add both `myClass<5, 6>` and `myClass<1, 4>` to the same array, since they are not the same type.

---

> also doesn't work
> `void addClassInstance(myClass *instance)`

Once again, `myClass` is not a type, instead it must be `myClass<someValue, anotherValue>`. So you must add the template parameters to the function:

```cpp
template<int someValue, int anotherValue>
void addClassInstance(myClass<someValue, anotherValue *instance){ ... }
```

In case you want to define this outside of the class:

```cpp
template<int numInstances>
template<int someValue, int anotherValue>
void myClassContainer<numInstances>::addClassInstance(myClass<someValue, anotherValue> *instance)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I commented in my original post, but I'll ask here as well. If I cannot add the myClass types with different template arguments to the same array, do you have any idea how to work around that, so that I can easily add them to a "group" and iteratively call member functions for all of them?

Comment: @Bapstack One way you can get around is to have the `myClass` inherit from a `baseClass`. Then in `myClassContainer`, you make `myClassInstances` to `baseClass *myClassInstances[numInstances]`. In `baseClass`, you want to make sure to define a virtual function for each function that might be called on `myClassInstances[i]`. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/EfPznabvb